# How to check if an area is inside certain bounds in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 'Snakes' like game where the player eats the food and then the food randomly gets spawned in a different location. The complexity is that the scene has some square obstacles and the player has to maneuver through those obstacles to eat the food without colliding with the obstacles. The only issue I'm facing is that the food sometimes spawns on top of the obstacles, I want to fix that.

I followed this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2Cs71rDlUg .
Where the guy teaches how to prevent spawn overlap. It worked for me to some extent, that is the center of the food never spawns inside the obstacles but, the edges still collide. I want to prevent the edge collisions too.

The guy uses center of the food object to check for collision and not the whole area of the food(which is a circle with circle collider).

I've also tried using: Layer mask and all Physics2d Overlap functions.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class foodspawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static FoodSpawner2 instance;
    public float xbound;
    public float ybound;
    public GameObject foodPrefab;
    public GameObject currentFood;
    public LayerMask mask;

    public Vector2 one = new Vector2(50f, 50f);
    public Vector2 two = new Vector2(-50f, -50f);

    public float radius;
    public Collider2D[] collidersss;
    //Spawns the food for the first time
    void Start()
    {
        FoodLoaction();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //Spawns the food when it gets eaten by the snake
        if (currentFood == null)
        {
            FoodLoaction();
        }
        FoodLoaction();
    }

    public void FoodLoaction()
    {
        Vector2 SpawnPos = new Vector2();
        bool canSpawnHere = false;
        int safetynet = 0;

        while (!canSpawnHere)
        {
            float xPos = Random.Range(-xbound, xbound);
            float yPos = Random.Range(-ybound, ybound);

            SpawnPos = new Vector2(xPos, yPos);
            canSpawnHere = PreventSpawnOverlap(SpawnPos);

            if (canSpawnHere)
            {
                break;
            }

            safetynet++;

            if (safetynet > 50)
            {
                break;
                Debug.Log("toooooooo");
            }
        }

        currentFood = Instantiate(foodPrefab, SpawnPos, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

    }

    public bool PreventSpawnOverlap(Vector2 spawnPos)
    {
        collidersss = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, radius, mask);
        for (int i = 0; i < collidersss.Length; i++)
        {
            Vector2 centerpoint = collidersss[i].bounds.center;
            float width = collidersss[i].bounds.extents.x;
            float height = collidersss[i].bounds.extents.y;

            float leftExtent = centerpoint.x - width;
            float rightExtent = centerpoint.x + width;
            float lowerExtent = centerpoint.y - height;
            float upperExtent = centerpoint.y + height;

            if (spawnPos.x >= leftExtent && spawnPos.x <= rightExtent)
            {
                if (spawnPos.y >= lowerExtent && spawnPos.y <= upperExtent)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The video never explains how to check the bounds of the food. Any kind of help with be much appreciated.

Comment: try this: `public bool PreventSpawnOverlap(Vector2 spawnPos)
{
        collidersss = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(spawnPos, radius, mask); 
        return collidersss.Length == 0;
}`, change `radius` to be the radius of your food (you could do this programmatically), and make sure `mask` only collides with obstacles.

Comment: Thank you for the input but, it didn't help. Results are same as before. Nothing changed.

Comment: Need to see what's going on. Add `Debug.Drawline(DrawLine(spawnPos, spawnPos+Vector2.right, Color.magenta, 30f, false); Debug.Drawline(DrawLine(spawnPos, spawnPos-Vector2.right, Color.magenta, 30f, false); Debug.Drawline(DrawLine(spawnPos, spawnPos+Vector2.up, Color.magenta, 30f, false); Debug.Drawline(DrawLine(spawnPos, spawnPos-Vector2.up, Color.magenta, 30f, false);` above the `return collidersss.Length == 0;`. Then include some screenshots of these lines appearing when food is placed, especially when food is placed inside a wall.